# Что-либо "общественное" может быть противопоставлено "природному"?

Tags: точное-словоупотребление

> Здесь есть несколько очень разных купален, **несколько общественных,
>   несколько природных** (ну, это тоже на любителя), где ты можешь войти в
>   эту воду вдоль быстрого течения.

Надо ли уточнять, почему входить в воду нужно вдоль течения?

Comment: *входить в воду нужно вдоль течения* - хорошо бы уточнить, это как? ))) Входить в воду можно или перпендикулярно течениб - или под углом к нему. "Вдоль течения" даже плыть нельзя. Только располагаться. )))

Answer (score 1):

> Здесь есть несколько очень разных купален, несколько общественных,
>   несколько природных (ну, это тоже на любителя), где ты можешь войти в
>   эту воду вдоль быстрого течения.

Не вижу явного противоречия, да, признаться, и противопоставления не вижу.
"Природные" я бы заменил на "естественные", но это уже по обстоятельствам.

А вот с "вдоль течения" - полный умслопогас. Не могу представить себе это движение.

Вот правильное использования оборота "вдоль течения".

> втором случае перемещаться при поклевке будет не весь шнур, лежащий на
>   воде, а только его выпрямленная вдоль течения часть

Что-то неподвижное ориентировано "вдоль течения"
Двигаться же можно по течению, и против него. Или поперек течения, под углом...